# Three buttons on push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I want to have 3 buttons on push notification. I followed [**this**](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/) tutorial for adding buttons. But this creates only two buttons. I modified the code to add another button but it seems that it all depends on **destructive** property of `UIMutableUserNotificationAction`. It can be either true or false.
How may I add a third button ?

Comment: Starting in ios10 you can add up to 4 options inside the notification detail view using 'UserNotification' & 'UserNotificationUI' frameworks. I'm not sure this is possible to have more than two options using 'UILocalNotification' API. 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated in favor of newer APIs in iOS10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than 2 buttons in notification if notification type selected as alerts from iOS device setting. unless in notification tray or device lock mode then you will get only 2 buttons.

destructive property is different thing, when you keep it "true" that button will display with red color, default it is "false" and display button with blue color when you slide notification.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently its not possible, max of 2 actions can be kept in notification in Minimal Context (UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal) but you can have upto 4 actions in Default Context (UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault)

Minimal Context defines the actions which will be visible on swiping the notifications. Default context is when the notification is shown as an alert. From iOS10 onwards it might be possible to have more buttons as Apple is introducing 2 new frameworks i.e, UserNotification, UserNotificationUI

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017084-DontLinkElementID_2